# ASP .NET 4.0 How do I Redirect/Override the default CDN path for ScriptManager when EnableCDN=true

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, cdn

I am using the EnableCdn=true in my ScriptManager so that WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd are overridden with static links to JS libraries at the MS CDN service as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true"  />
```

How do I override the CDN URLs or service so that I can retrieve the scripts over HTTPS from the MS CDN service rather than HTTP to avoid the browser mixed mode message? or for that matter a different or my own CDN service entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your question :)
[Loading AjaxControlToolkit Scripts from Microsoft's CDN using ScriptManager/ToolkitManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035573/loading-ajaxcontroltoolkit-scripts-from-microsofts-cdn-using-scriptmanager-toolk/5944102#5944102)

Answer (score 0):

Now, there’s a new property on WebResourceAttribute: CdnPath:

```
[assembly: WebResource("Foo.js", "application/x-javascript", 
    CdnPath = "http://foo.com/foo/bar/foo.js")]
```

[More info here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/11/23/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements.aspx)

Comment: I am wanting to do this globally one time and not on a script by script basis and am struggling with where/how to do that.