# What is the difference between ASP.NET Ajax 4 and Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cdn, ajax.net

I'm not able to find a clear explanation about the difference between ASP.NET Ajax 4 and Ajax Control Toolkit.

- Do they are the same library from MS?

Also using the ScriptManager EnableCDN property to redirect all ASP.NET framework script requests to the Microsoft Ajax ...I will get all library from ASP.NET Ajax 4 and Ajax Control Toolkit too?

Thanks guys to help me understand :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX is the base AJAX library which is now part of the ASP.NET framework, so it is supported by Microsoft. It only includes the controls like Script manager, UpdatePanel, etc which will let you create AJAXified applications using ASP.NET.

AjaxControlToolkit is a "ToolKit" project to provide AJAX controls that you can use in you projects. It uses the ASP.NET AJAX base library for creating these controls. As it is a Codeplex project, no support will be provided by Microsoft officially(You will get community support).

Update: About the CDN part, I could see this question on stackoverflow,  I haven't tried it myself. [Loading AjaxControlToolkit Scripts from Microsoft's CDN using ScriptManager/ToolkitManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035573/loading-ajaxcontroltoolkit-scripts-from-microsofts-cdn-using-scriptmanager-toolk)